# Construct a function that is differentiable only on the rationals.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, complex-analysis

In the spirit of having handy counter examples, is it possible to construct a function that is differentiable on all of the rational numbers and nowhere else?

Similarly, if a function is holomorphic at a point, must it always be holomorphic in an open neighborhood around that point?

Constructive proofs and counterexamples will be given priority.

Comment: Doesn't *holomorphic at p* by definition mean *complex differentiable in a neighbourhood of p*? If so, the answer to your second question is trivially yes.

Comment: 'Holomorphic at a point' is *defined* to be 'holomorphic on some neighbourhood of that point'

Comment: For the rationals question, the answer is yes by Zahorski's Theorem.

Comment: André is [right](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=BSMF_1946__74__147_0)

Comment: I might have misspoke, I meant to say C-differentiable instead of holomorphic. I don't know if you distinguish between the two at a point. A function is C-differentiable if the difference quotients have a limit at a point. The function needs to be defined in an open neighborhood, but certainly not C-differentiable (I think). Also, a function need not necessarily be C-differentiable in a neighborhood by definition, so the top two responses are wrong with the definition I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not checked in detail, something like  $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \cos (\pi \; n! \; x)/2^n$$ may be a function that is differentiable on all of the rational numbers and nowhere else.