# Is there any continuous function that is only differentiable on $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I am looking for a continuous function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ so that $f$ is differentiable in $x$, if and only if $x \in \mathbb Q$.

I already know there is no function that is continuous everywhere in $\mathbb Q$ but nowhere outside of it, but I wonder if something similar can be said about differentiability. If not, how could one prove that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be

Comment: I haven't had any measure theory, which makes reading this quite hard. It says that "a subset D of $\mathbb R$ can be the discontinuity set for some derivative if and only if D is an Fσ first category (i.e. an Fσ meager) subset of $\mathbb R$". Does that mean that $f$ can't be differentiable only on $\mathbb Q$, since the irrationals are not Fσ?

Comment: Maybe an easier argument is the one which comes a little earlier: “the continuity set has cardinality $c$ in every subinterval of $J$”. Here $c$ is the cardinality of the reals, so in particular the continuity set must be uncountable (which of course the rationals aren't).

Comment: @HansLundmark As I pondered a bit more, I came up with a function $g(x) = x^2 h(x)$ where $h(x)$ is nowhere differentiable. $g(x)$ is only differentiable in $x = 0$, so the set where $g(x)$ is differentiable is certainly not uncountable, nor empty. What goes wrong then with the argument you gave in this example? I noticed that the other thread discusses _continuity_ of the derivative where I am looking for a function $f$ that is only _differentiable_ at certain points ($\mathbb Q$). Is that a significant difference?

Comment: That thread is talking about everywhere-differentiable functions, and is asking about on what sets can the derivative be discontinuous. Your question is about everywhere-continuous functions and is asking on what sets the function can be not differentiable.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: You're right, of course! So this question is quite different. (And my earlier comment is irrelevant here since it refers to the situation in that other thread.)

Comment: I'm tumped. If you don't get any more input soon, then I suggest cross-posting this on Math OverFlow

Comment: After answering, I found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111443/construct-a-function-that-is-differentiable-only-on-the-rationals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is a reference:*

Mark Lynch. *A Continuous Function That Is Differentiable Only at the Rationals.* Mathematics Magazine 86, no. 2 (2013): 132-35. [doi:10.4169/math.mag.86.2.132](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/math.mag.86.2.132).

> An explicit construction is given of a function that is continuous on an interval, and differentiable only at the rationals.

See also references within ([Zahorski's Theorem](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=BSMF_1946__74__147_0)) for a nonconstructive proof.